# visual studio 2013 error (C#): ioexception when loading user controle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ioexception

I keep getting an error (ioexception) when loading my user control into My Main application when making a windows form application in Microsoft VisualStudio Express 2013.

```
serverXml.Load(@"RetrieveServerNamesFromXML\XMLFile1.xml");
```

But when I use the complete path it gives no error at al and it loads.

```
serverXml.Load(@"C:\..\myproject\RetrieveServerNamesFromXML\XMLFile1.xml");
```

It only occurs when loading it into my designer, not when running the app. And the error is the following.

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\System32\RetrieveServerNameFromXML\XMLFile1.xml' at ...

For some reason it loots for the file in my system map and not local in the project file. Its strange because everything works perfect. Its just annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The Xml file cannot be found using the relative path, because your current path is something else  (Most probably the directory where your devenv.exe resides).

I think it would be better to prevent loading the xml file when loading the control in design-mode.

You can do that by putting the `serverXml.Load` statement inside an if clause:

```
if( DesignMode == false ){
   serverXml.Load (...);
}
```

(Note that the DesignMode property does not work inside a constructor, so if this code is placed in the constructor of your control, consider moving this code to an eventhandler for the `Load` event of the control).